# How to read just lists in a text file in Python?

Tags: python, list, text

I need to read a text file like this

```
bruce
chung
bruce@outlook.com
8893243
costarricense
divisa del informe colones
['nokia', 5277100.0, 'china']
['samsung', 10554200.0, 'turkey']
['apple', 52771000.0, 'argentina']
```

But I need to read just the lists inside the file and assign them into a new variable.

I've used this

```
data =[ast.literal_eval(x) for x in open("test.txt")]
registros = data
```

And it worked well before until I added the information of the user below.

Is there a way to read only the lists in the text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `str.startswith()` to check if the string starts with `'['` , and use `ast.literal_eval()` only if that is true. Example -

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    registros = [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in f if x.startswith('[')]
```

Demo -

```
>>> s = """bruce
... chung
... bruce@outlook.com
... 8893243
... costarricense
... divisa del informe colones
... ['nokia', 5277100.0, 'china']
... ['samsung', 10554200.0, 'turkey']
... ['apple', 52771000.0, 'argentina']""".splitlines()
>>> import ast
>>> registros = [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in s if x.startswith('[')]
>>> registros
[['nokia', 5277100.0, 'china'], ['samsung', 10554200.0, 'turkey'], ['apple', 52771000.0, 'argentina']]
```

---

For the updated requirements in the comments -

> How can I also read only the user info and assign it to a variable using this method?

Assuming any line that is not a list, is part of the user info

You can use a simple for loop, keep appending to a variable if the line does not start with `'['` , and if it does, use `ast.literal_eval()` on it, and append it to the `registros` list.

Example -

```
import ast
with open("test.txt") as f:
    user_info = ''
    registros = []
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('['):
            registros.append(ast.literal_eval(line))
        else:
            user_info += line
```

If the user_info would always just be 6 lines (as given in the comments) , you can also use -

```
import ast
with open("test.txt") as f:
    user_info = ''
    for i,line in enumerate(f):
        user_info += line
        if  i==5:
            break
    registros = [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in f if x.startswith('[')]
```

Comment: How can I also read only the user info and assign it to a variable using this method?

Comment: Can you be sure that its the first 6 lines? Or is it all lines before the first line with `[` ?

Comment: It will be allways 6 lines

Answer (score 1):

This should work, assuming you're not planning on using brackets for any purpose besides encapsulating lists.

```
import re
import ast

matches = []
data = open("test.txt", 'r').read()
for listString in re.findall(r"\[.*\]", data):
  matches.append(ast.literal_eval(listString))
```